# How do I iterate through methods/functions in a list in web2py

Tags: web2py

My code goes like:

```
m = ['first_time', 'first_day']
t = times()
def this():
    code.....
    for item in m:
        getattr(t, item)()
```

I tried another option of:

```
try:
    return  t.first_time()
    return t.first_day()
except AttributeError, e:
return e.message
```

These codes work well but only for the first method `first_time()`. How can I make iterate through all functions in m in `web2py`?

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be web2py specific. Anyway, what exactly do you want as a result? Does each method return a value? If so and you want all the values, you would need to store them in something like a list or tuple and return that.

Comment: Hi I stated that it iterates and return from the first function only.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't answered my question. What output are you expecting? You cannot have two return statements both execute in a single function call. If you want to return multiple values, you'll have to put them in some kind of data structure and return that. If there are no values to return, and the methods merely generate side effects, then no need to return at all.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. What I have in the code is a query keyword that iterates through the methods, if the keyword matches the requirements,  that function prints out an answer, if not, then the next method should be invoked

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. How do you determine if the keyword matches the requirements? Sounds like you can just do a loop, and once you have found the method that matches the requirements, just call it and return the result.